# How to set a limit of a character frequency or disable the onclick button on some conditions?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build a basic calculator. In my app, if someone double presses the mathematical signs(+,*,/,-), it should only allow the user to press the button one time if there is no number after the (+,*,/,-) signs. I am thinking and googling a whole but I cannot come to a solution.

I attached two pictures of what output I am getting and what output I expect. My pseudo-code is:-

1. If editText is not empty and
2. if the immediate characters after or before signs are not signs.(i.e: 1+1-2>acceptable)
   (i.e: 1++1--->not acceptable.disable the button or not repeat the signs.)

Here's my code for addButton:

```
  public void BtnAdd(View view) {


    if (display.getText().toString().matches(".*\\d.*")) {
        display("+");

    }

}
```

Here's my full code:

https://www.codepile.net/pile/63g8oKjb

The output I am getting:-

[image]

The output I expect:-

[image]

Are there any new concepts I need to do that I am not familiar with? I also need your suggestions for improving building logic. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if a string ends in a digit, you can use this

```
String currentTxt = display.getText().toString();

if( currentTxt.matches("^.*?\\d$") ) { // check that it ends with a number
    // allow adding a + symbol at the end
    display.setText(currentTxt + "+");
}
```

The `$` in the regex matches the end of the string, and the `^` matches the front of the string. So this matches a full string with zero or more characters (`.*`) followed by an ending digit (`?\\d`). You can always test Regex patterns [online](https://regex101.com/).

In this case, a regex isn't strictly necessary though, you could also just get the last character and call `isDigit`

```
String currentTxt = display.getText().toString();

if( !currentTxt.isEmpty() && Character.isDigit(currentTxt.charAt(currentTxt.length()-1)) ) { // check that it ends with a number
    // allow adding a + symbol at the end
    display.setText(currentTxt + "+")
}
```

Comment: Wish I could upvote by 100. Thank you very much. I am learning android for 2+ weeks. I know core java only. What should I learn to improve my logic?

Comment: The code samples [here](https://developer.android.com/samples) can be a good place to look to understand Android design patterns.